# Passing spinner value from fragment to activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

I'm trying to send the value of the spinner from the fragment to the Main activity, trying to use intent to do so, but it's not working really. I am using toast in the main activity to check if the value is passing but it isn't

Any help?

Fragment Code:

```
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_language, container, false);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.language_Spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            // this line will get you the selected item of the spinner
            String selectedValue = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            Intent i1 = new Intent(getActivity(), PetsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("languageValue", selectedValue);
            i1.putExtra("languageValue", selectedValue);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {
        }
    });
    return rootView;

}
```

Main Activity

```
String languageChoice = getIntent().getStringExtra("languageValue");

    Toast.makeText(this, languageChoice, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But obviously it's not working.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If this fragment is a part of that activity, then you don't need to have an intent

you can create a method in your activity assume you name it `getSpinnerValue(String value)`. Then in your fragment use `getActivity()` or `requireActivity()`, cast it to your activity class, and call `getSpinnerValue(value)`

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        // this line will get you the selected item of the spinner
        String selectedValue = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSpinnerValue(selectedValue);

        // ... reset of code
```

Comment: And what should I add in the getSpinnerValue method ?

Comment: Add what you want to do with the spinner value in your activity, as you're asking about `Passing spinner value from fragment to activity`